# .NET SDK project type reference issue

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-project

I have this in my new style .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.Data.SqlServerCe">
      <HintPath>..\OtherProject\System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

But VS keeps resolving the reference to:

```
C:\Users\Me\.nuget\packages\microsoft.sqlserver.compact\4.0.8876.1\lib\net40\System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll
```

But this is the wrong assembly version (the one in the file system is 4.0.0.1, and the nuget one is 4.0.0.0)

What do I need to add to my csproj?

Comment: Hmya, programmers like the new project format too much.  The IDE and MSBuild tooling for it has a long bug list and it is not getting smaller.  HintPath is [on that list as well](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/107).  When you are in Rome then it is best to talk Italian, they'll understand PackageReference.

Comment: I will switch back to the old csproj format for now, I think

Comment: Are you able to use 4.0.8854.1?  If so, there's a nuget package for it.  I would always rely on nuget packages instead of hard references.  It's not great to commit binaries to git anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try specifying `Version=4.0.0.1`, or any version you desire, in the `<Reference>` tag:

```
<Reference Include="System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.1">
  <HintPath>..\OtherProject\System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```